# Best implementation of fgets size argument?

Tags: c, string, sizeof, fgets

I've been comparing the two statements, which use fgets to read a string from standard input.

```
char array[10];
fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin) ;
fgets(array, (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])) , stdin);
```

Technically, both are identical, with the exception that method 2 is redundant, since fgets can only accept a char array. 
My thought process is that since fgets takes a char *s argument there isn't any need for the second example(chars are one byte, so division by 1 is redundant) .

However, when dealing with arrays of a different data type (in a for loop for example), the second method of determining the size of the array is required.

The second statement looks ugly, but are there any other major disadvantages of using it? Here are some advantages I can think of:

1. Teaches correct way of determining  array sizes for other applications, e.g. for for() loops.
2. Does not break down if (not applicable for this example, as fgets only takes char arrays) the array type is changed

Comment: What do you mean by *dealing with arrays of a different data type*, provide a simple example.

Comment: If we need to loop over a int array[10],
Rather than writing a for loop and figuring out the number of elements yourself, it's simpler to write for (int i=0; i < (sizeof(array) /sizeof (array[0]); ++i) would correctly loop over the entire array

Comment: How is that related to `fgets`?

Comment: Also the parenthesis around `sizeof` argument are redundant: `sizeof array / sizeof *array` like `return (0);` or `x = (1) + (2);`

Comment: Use the standard `ARRAY_SIZE(array)` macro, for readability.

Comment: @abelenky:  Where did that "standard" come from?  I have never seen it before.

Comment: It is available on all platforms, and typically found in `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1):

The second form, shown below, could get you an unpleasant surprise.

```
fgets(array, (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])) , stdin);
```

Specifically, the second argument to `fgets` represents the maximum number of `char` values (less 1 for the trailing NUL) which `array` can hold.

So, if `array` is declared as

```
char array[SOME_NUMBER];
```

Then `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` would yield SOME_NUMBER. But what if it were defined as one of the following:

```
int array[SOME_NUMBER];
char array[SOME_NUMBER][SOME_OTHER_NUMBER];
```

In the both cases, it would yield `SOME_NUMBER` because it calculates the number of elements in the array. But it completely ignores the **size** of each element. Imagine in the second case that `SOME_NUMBER` was significantly larger than `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER`. The `fgets` would fill the first element of `array` and then overflow into one or more of the subsequent elements. Here you really wanted to pass in `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER`.

The take-away here is that you need to be explicit in the value you pass to `fgets`. For the normal case (a single-dimension `char` array), `sizeof(array)` is fine. For an array of `char` arrays (as shown above), then either `SOME_OTHER_NUMBER` or `sizeof(array[0])` should be used.

The `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` approach should never be used, because it is *not* calculating a size which inherently relates to `sizeof(char)`. It is calculating the number of elements in `array` - regardless of their size.